# Do hydrogen peroxide stabilizers affect oxidizing ability

Tags: redox, stability

I plan to use hydrogen peroxide for a redox reaction in oxidizing $\ce{I-}$ to $\ce{I}$.  I found 20 volume hydrogen peroxide as a hair developer, but it contains stabilizer.  I imagined these would have little effect on its oxidizing potential, but I wanted to make sure.  Will any of the common stabilizers used for hydrogen peroxide inhibit its oxidizing ability.

Comment: Take a tiny droplet of each solution and check if they will react. Chemistry is an experimental science, after all.

Comment: I imagine the purpose of the "stabiliser" is there to inhibit the disproportionation to H2O and O2, not to stop it from oxidising other stuff. Although there might very well be some effect since disproportionation is essentially H2O2 oxidising itself... Ivan is right, just test it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't hinder your oxidation much, just keep in mind they will still likely be around when your reaction is finished.